# Why are images corrupted in my zip file?

Tags: java, io, zip, java-7

I'm generating a zip file in java containing a mix of text and image files, this works fine on one computer but on another my image files are corrupt (same java version and OS); the resulting file sizes are the same but the image will not open in an image editor/viewer, text files are fine.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
zos.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);
addZipEntry(zos, "/forms/images/calendar.gif", "images/calendar.gif");
addZipEntry(zos, "/forms/templ/header.php", "templ/header.php");
zos.close();

private void addZipEntry(ZipOutputStream zos, String resourcePath, String entryName) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entryName));
    zos.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
    zos.closeEntry();
}
```

Any ideas why the images are getting corrupted?

[Here's a visual binary comparison between a corrupt image and the original.](http://pastehtml.com/view/b9rrgr0pl.html)

Comment: I suggest you create a smaller example illustrating the problem (exclude the references to ClassLoaders and stuff), and perhaps also upload the images causing troubles.

Comment: Run a diff tool on the images to see exactly how much the data has changed.

Comment: @Stijn I've added a link to a visual comparison, it doesn't really tell me much personally but maybe someone more enlightened can see what's going on.

Comment: A lot of data has changed, but it's remarkable that nearly all changed bytes have the value `0x3F` now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the tool you use to extract your ZIP file treats your image as ASCII text, replacing any value higher than or equal to 0x80 as an unknown character, replacing it with a questionmark (0x3F).

Comment: I use the same tool to extract the images on a working zip, I've also tried different extraction tools.

Comment: Are you by any chance using FTP to transfer the ZIP file?

Comment: This answer put me on the right track, my app build includes an ant filter task and it seems this was corrupting the images as  described above. It must be an encoding difference that causes this to happen on one machine and not another. Excluding the images from the filter solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas why the images are getting corrupted?

That would depend on what `IOUtils.toByteArray(is)` does.

Comment: That was my first instinct, I tried taking IOUtils out of the equation and I still had the same problem.

Comment: @Phill replacing it with what?

Comment: `byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
            zos.write(buf, 0, len);
        }`